# Does Marchesa and a creature with modular work together?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I control [Marchesa, the Black Rose](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Marchesa%2C%20the%20Black%20Rose) and [Arcbound Ravager](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arcbound%20Ravager).

When Ravager dies, will the abilities of Marchesa and Ravager both trigger? If you can confirm it with rules, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Both are triggered abilities, both would be added to the stack when the Arcbound Ravager dies and resolve independently. It's certainly possible, and indeed happens quite often in the game, that multiple triggered abilities trigger from the same event.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I just realized that Marchesa actually triggers twice (I think?).

Comment: @Rainbolt Marchesa's ability in question does trigger on death and creates a delayed trigger ability. That ability then triggers at the beginning of the next end step.

Answer (score 1):

If Ravager dies the modular ability will trigger. As I'm sure you are aware dies means (700.4. The term dies means “is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.”) So the trigger goes on the stack when Ravager dies. You get to pick what creature the modular ability goes on to. Then during the end step marchesa's ability will trigger bringing Ravager back. The reason the ability triggers is because Ravager had the counter when he hit the graveyard and his ability didn't actually trigger until he is in the graveyard.

Comment: Actually, like Hackworth said in my answer above, Marchesa's ability triggers at the same time as the Ravager's ability. This triggered ability, when it resolves, sets up a delayed triggered ability that is triggered during the end step.

Comment: Also, tiny nitpickery: there are ways for Ravager to die that _don't_ trigger Marchesa.  For instance, if your opponent puts Spike Cannibal into play and gets to move the +1/+1 counters from Arcbound Ravager onto it, then the game state will 'see' Ravager dying to a state-based effect as a 0/0 creature, and since it died with zero counters on it (those counters having moved), Marchesa's ability won't return it to play at EOT.